# only one launchdarkly client can exist at a time but another client already exists? and other devtools warnings

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image]

When running our react web application both locally and in production, I am receiving the following errors and warnings in the Console. This error appears in the Console tab of Chrome Dev Tools when I am running our react web application both locally and in production.

The only warning or error that makes a modicum of sense is the `youtube.com` error as we have a link to a YouTube video on our home page, and perhaps we are not properly displaying the video.

I am at a complete loss for the rest of these warnings/errors and how to resolve them. We do not use `LaunchDarklyClient` in our web application at all. These `DevTools failed to load source map:...` warnings don't provide any context, and the links lead to no where.

Notably, when I run our website in incognito mode, the `LaunchDarklyClient` error goes away, as do the `DevTools failed to load...` warnings. Does that mean these warnings/errors are potentially due to some chrome extensions I am using, or something else related to my local chrome?

Comment: Same thing happened to me.  I uninstalled the composeAI chrome extension, and it went away. I did tell them about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did some testing by toggling extensions on and off:

- adblock plus 3.16 is responsible for `DevTools failed to load source map:...` warnings
- compose AI 1.0.0-rc1 is responsible for `LaunchDarklyClient` errors
- `unrecognized feature: web-share` is not related to any of my extensions (still getting this warning when toggling all extensions off)

Still not sure if there's a way to hide or remove these warnings/errors other than to disable these chrome extensions.

Comment: Thanks. Compose AI is responsible for this type of error in my browser.

Comment: Getting this with Compose AI too, currently version 1.3.0.

Comment: After disabling Compose AI chrome extension issue is resolved, Thanks

Comment: so annoyed at compose ai, how irresponsible of them,.....